# jQuery: If key exists in array, get value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to see if a certain key exists in an array, and if so, return it's value:

```
if(jQuery.inArray(live_ids.grade, item.SizePrice) !== -1) {

    console.log(item.SizePrice);

}
```

This will return:

```
{"8":"15.00","7":"20.00","1":"6.00","6":"11.00","2":"7.00","3":"8.00","4":"9.00","5":"10.00","11":"20.00","9":"10.00","10":"15.00","13":""}
```

Now, `live_ids.grade` = 9, so I want to be able to return `10.00`... how do I do that?

Comment: use .each() or http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

Comment: item.SizePrice[live_ids.grade] will return value at that index

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here you check if the number is in the obj than execute else show error.

```js
var obj = {
    "8":"15.00",
    "7":"20.00",
    "1":"6.00",
    "6":"11.00",
    "2":"7.00",
    "3":"8.00",
    "4":"9.00",
    "5":"10.00",
    "11":"20.00",
    "9":"10.00",
    "10":"15.00",
    "13":""
};

var number = 9;

if(number in obj){
    alert(obj[number])
} else {
    alert("This number does not exists")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`item.SizePrice` appears to be an `Object`, not an `Array`. You can use `for..in` loop on the object , `break` the loop after `console.log()` called

```js
var items = {
    "8": "15.00",
    "7": "20.00",
    "1": "6.00",
    "6": "11.00",
    "2": "7.00",
    "3": "8.00",
    "4": "9.00",
    "5": "10.00",
    "11": "20.00",
    "9": "10.00",
    "10": "15.00",
    "13": ""
  },
  n = 9;

for (var prop in items) {
  if (items[n]) {
    console.log(items[n]);
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var a={"k1": 100, "k2": 200, "k3": 300};
        var ky=prompt("enter key :");
        for (var k in a){
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        if(k==ky){
         alert("Key is " + k + ", value is" + a[k]);
        }
    }
}   
    </script>
```